# VBA Access Enable/Disable Ribbon Group/Button Based on Form Button Action

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

**Problem:**

I want to `Enable` or `Disable` a button group based on a Form `Button click`.

[image]

1. On Application Open - The Accounting Group should be `disabled`.
2. The Dashboard Form is opened automatically on Application Open
3. User Clicks a button - based on their permissions certain buttons in the group will become `enabled`.

   How can I trigger an invalidation that loops through all the Ribbon button controls to `enable/disable` based on permissions?

*Note: I'm coding in VBA Access 2013*

Comment: See this: http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Access_-_Ribbons:Callbacks:getEnabled

Comment: Combined with the `CommandBars`-Collection.

Comment: The Xml code can go in a table called USysRibbons. Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-Ribbon-45E110B9-531C-46ED-AB3A-4E25BC9413DE?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: @KostasK. this is based on an action on the Ribbon - is it possible to trigger something based on a form action that affects the Ribbon?

Comment: @Justin Yes, the action needs to set a Boolean variable (enabled true/false) which will be fed to the ribbon control through `InvalidateControl`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/iribbonui-invalidatecontrol-method-office

Comment: @KostasK. When I tried this I got an error that my object was not set. Do you know what this could be?

Comment: Edit: I've managed to get it to work! Thanks @KostasK.